# Persistent volume for wwwroot/storage folder of Asp.ner Core App

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, cloud-hosting

I have a middle size asp.net core application (online store). One of the functions is uploading pictures for products. Also, I want to host my application in Kubernetes in a cloud.

I know that a common solution to this problem is to use some S3-like file storage. But my store quite little and I don't want to complicate it very much.

So I want to use some folder in `mySite/wwwroot` like `mySite/wwwroot/storage` to storage all pictures:

- It's simple to work with
- I can create a simple URL for my pictures like `mysite.com/storage/picture.png`

---

1. Is it somehow possible to map `mySite/wwwroot/storage` to some persistent volume?
2. What hostname should I use? It is easy to mount images like Postgres because Postgres use some hardcoded folder to store data (`/var/lib/postgresql/data`).

I understand that it restricts all replicas of my site only by one node.

Comment: Do you have more than one worker node in your k8s cluster ? If not, you can think of `hostPath` `persistentVolume` https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#create-a-persistentvolume

Comment: @mario I want to use it, but the problem is exactly path. Looks like hostPath relies on some fixed path across the whole node. For example /var/lib/postgresql/data folder of Postgres, etc. But the wwwroot will be inside some dynamics "folders" on one node (because of multiple replicas). Is it possible to mount wwwroot/storage folder of all replicas into one physical folder?

Comment: What do you mean by *dynamic folders* ? Could you explain your solution in more detail ? If you use some cloud platform there are plenty of ready storage solutions available out there that are supported by Kubernetes and I would recommend you to use one of them rather than reinvent the wheel. You can always set up your own NFS server but I wouldn't say it will be simpler or cheaper solution than those which are offered by cloud providers.

Comment: @mario I think you right. I struggle sometimes to make my wwwroot solution works, but it already takes more time than simple integration with some S3 service